# How to disable SSL Pinning on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, http, ssl, dio, sslpinning

We are using Flutter for app development. Our security testers said that we need to disable SSL Pinning in Flutter code so they can run some test. We couldn't do it. We use Dio package for HTTP request. How can we disable SSL Pinning on Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

SSL Pinning is not the default behavior. So you don't need to disable it if it had not already been enabled.

Comment: I guess these codes are for checking if there is a SSL Pinning and setting a certificate. But we don't need to do these. We need to disable SSL Pinning in Flutter application.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point. As mentioned here, SSL Pinning is not the default behavior. So you don't need to disable it if it had not already been enabled.

https://www.reddit.com/r/flutterhelp/comments/q2qsnk/comment/hfn0qdq/

Comment: https://medium.com/surfstudio/ssl-pinning-in-flutter-apps-254e01e57965

Comment: if you edit your answer as "SSL Pinning is not the default behavior. So you don't need to disable it if it had not already been enabled." then i can mark your answer as an accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: I edited the answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar problem. The solution was pretty simple. The http packet automatically prevents the network from listening.

To fix this problem and resubmit it for penetration testing, make these changes to the **main.dart** file:

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return super.createHttpClient(context)..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
    }

    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..findProxy = (uri) {
        return "PROXY localhost:8080";
      }
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}
```

and add this line in **main()** method:

```
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
```

Comment: what those code actually do? is that to disguise the security testers only?

Comment: In IOS its work ?

Answer (score 0):

SSL Pinning is not a default behaviour of flutter but Dio library do reject self signed certificate that we install, when using proxy server in order to intercept API Calls. Dio library provide a call back on badCertificateCallback when it find some self signed certificate in between the connection.

```
(dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate =
    (client) {
      client.findProxy = (uri) => "PROXY 192.168.1.10:8888;";
      client.badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
    };
```

if you return true in client.badCertificateCallback system will accept the self signed certificate and will call the server and you will be able intercept the call in proxy server but if you return false it will reject the certificate and API call will not proceed and you won't be able to make call to the server. By default it is false.

```
  client.findProxy = (uri) => "PROXY 192.168.1.10:8888;"; //here you need to write your own proxy local address and port number
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Flutter doesn't have SSL pinning by default, all it's happening is because of the DIO package you used it's blocking self-signed certificates so you have two options to disable SSL pinning.

1- Ask your pen.

2- Use Dio-provided callback client.badCertificateCallback and return true to it so your pen-testing team will be able to decrypt the SSL traffic.